# New arc4random()%x; different from Previous number

Tags: ios, random, arc4random

I have this line of code to calculate a random number:

```
    myRand = arc4random()%24; //0:23
```

What's the most efficient way of adding to this in order for this not to generate the same number it previously generated.

I'm not trying to shuffle all 24, as I do want repeats, just preferably not 2 of the same number directly after each other...

I thought of storing the previous number separately, then comparing it and if matching, just do it again, but I couldn't figure out away if for example the same number came out 3 times in a row... Unlikely I know, but it's possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm just generating a random number which corresponds to a location of an enemy based within a circle (with 24 segments)... they spawn in each segment based on the number generated... I would like them not to spawn in the same location twice in a row...

Comment: Add more informationto the question. Also, if "3 times in a row" what should happen? And instead of `arc4random()%24;` use `arc4random_uniform(24);`, that will eliminate any bias from the remaninder operation.

Comment: The numbers aren't manipulated so I thought `arc24random` would be ok.... Nothing happens, as I mentioned, I don't want the previous number to appear again, and the only way I could think of comparing it was to store it and compare the two.. but obviously say the same number was generated 5 times in a row, my method wouldn't be able to compare them all... Hence asking how this could all be dealt with before the number having a chance to appear more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to the previously generated number in an ivar.

```
NSInteger lastRandom;
```

and initialize it to something like `-1`.

Then when you want a new random number you can do something like:

```
NSInteger newRandom;
do {
    newRandom = arc4random_uniform(24);
while (newRandom != lastRandom);
lastRandom = newRandom;
```

This little loop will ensure your new random number is different from the last you generated.

Comment: Oh sweet. I always forget `do while` and never seem to find the need for it...  Now I have :D

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is much like a card shuffle: you want 24 values to come up in a randomized order, and like cards you want to take each out of the deck after it comes up so it doesn't come up again (until you reshuffle the deck).

GameplayKit in iOS 9 and later provide utilities for randomization tasks like this. In particular, this one is solved by the [`GKShuffledDistribution`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKShuffledDistribution_Class/index.html) class:

```
id<GKRandom> dist = [GKShuffledDistribution distributionForDieWithSideCount:24];
myRand = [dist nextInt];
```

This one doesn't repeat until all 24 values have been exhausted.

More generally, using `GKRandom` (etc) instead of `arc4random` (etc) gives you multiple options for controlling randomized behaviors in your game: making sure that different randomized game systems don't influence each other, making sure you can repeat certain random sequences for testing or between client and server, making random numbers that follow a specific pattern, and so on.

Comment: No, the OP is not looking for anything like a card shuffle.

Comment: I'm really bad at explaining things... I have an enemy in 1 of 24 locations, an enemy is spawned on 1 of 24 locations, based on the number generation... so I need numbers to repeat, just not 2 of the same directly one after the other... so it could generate 1,2,6,5,19,4,19,2,20,5,7... that would be fine. This is handy to know though. Thanks for posting.

Comment: `distributionForDieWithSideCount` is neat even though it does not answer the question.